# Does there exist a Similarity transformation that isolates the null-space of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

Say I have an $n \times n$, real, symmetric, positive semi-definite matrix with $m$ zero eigenvalues.

Can I find a similarity transformation that removes the null space and gives me an $(n-m) \times (n-m)$, positive definite matrix?

Of-course, I mean finding a transformation at a cost lower than that for the full eigen-decomposition.

Comment: @YiFan I don't know how to begin going about it, other than numerically finding the full eigen spectrum.

Comment: Hint: the row space of a matrix is the orthogonal complement of its null space, and your matrix is symmetric.